# kind of VS a little

Tags: adverbs

While I was learning "kind of" and "a little" based on the below captured meanings, I realized the below points.

(1) "kind of" can be placed before verbs and after be-verbs. It is so free in light of the place where it could be.

(2) "kind of" can modify Verbs, Adjectives, and Nouns.

whereas,

(3) I have not watched "a little" placed before Verbs. Of course, "a little" is always positioned after be-verbs.

(4) So I guess, "a little" generally modifies Verbs and Adjectives.

Do you think I learned them in the correct way?

[image]

```
Versus
```

[image]

Comment: _A little_  is standard English. _Kind of_ (in this sense) is informal, as the dictionary says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the summery in the question is good. However "a little" can also be used to modify a noun, with a meaning of "a small amount". In this use it is an adjective, not an adverb. For example

- > I take a little sugar in my tea.
- > I needed a little time to learn the process.

The phrase "kind of" can al;so be placed after a verb that is not a form of "be" The meanign is much the same as if it were before the verb. For example:

> I wanted to go, kind of, but I didn't think I could spare the time.
> I like her, kind of, but I don't feel comfortable with her.

This construction is often used when expressing doubt or uncertainty.

Also, "kind of" can be used to mean "type of" This is a totally different sense and usage. For example:

> Writing is a different kind of communication than speaking.

---

By the way, the expression "the below X" whicu was used in the question twice is awkward and unnatural, at least in US English (and I think in UK English, I am not sure about Indian English) The samples in the question xould be rephrased as:

- > the meanings captured below
- > the points below (or the points listed below).